# Javascript/Jquery: issue with append in cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get Flickr gallery via API/Json. My issue with my code is that the gallery that I fetch has ~ 30 picture, but this snippet:

```
$.each(data.album.content,function (index,content)
        {
            album_container.append(column);
         [...]
}
```

Appends only one `<div>` to the container, and not 30, but appends in right way 30 `a/img` to this unique `column`. I cannot figure why and how solve it.

Thank you for your help!

```
var album_container = $('div#album');

function callGetAjax(url)
{
    return $.get(url,{});
}    

function getAlbum(feed_url)
{
    callGetAjax(absolute_path+'/feed/'+feed_url)
    .success(function(data)
    {
    })
    .error(function(xhr, statusText)
    {//console.log(statusText);
    })
    .done(function(data)
    {
        var loaded = 0;
        album_title = data.album.album_title;
        $('h1#gallery-title').html(album_title);
        var column  = $('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2"></div>');
        $.each(data.album.content,function (index,content)
        {
            album_container.append(column);
            $('<a/>')
                .append($('<img class="img-responsive">').prop('src', content.photo))
                .prop('href', content.target)
                .prop('title', content.title)
                .attr('data-gallery', '')
                .appendTo(column)
                .colorbox({rel:'gallery', speed:0, maxWidth:'95%', maxHeight:'95%'});
        });


    }); 
}
```

Current HTML result:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
 <a href=".."><img src="..." /></a>
 <a href=".."><img src="..." /></a>
 <a href=".."><img src="..." /></a>
 [...]
</div>
```

HTML that I need:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
     <a href=".."><img src="..." /></a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
     <a href=".."><img src="..." /></a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
     <a href=".."><img src="..." /></a>
</div>

[...]
```

Comment: Are the 30 images supposed to go into the column?

Comment: Edited question with current and espected HTML. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `.append()` will move the HTML node around the DOM tree when the node already exists in your document. In your case, you have declared:

```
var column  = $('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2"></div>')
```

…*outside* of your `$.each()` loop, therefore causing it to be repeatedly moved around inside `album_container`, instead of being *cloned* as you have expected. Therefore, what you would do is to declare it within your loop, such that the instance is not outside the scope of your loop:

```
var album_container = $('div#album');

function callGetAjax(url)
{
    return $.get(url,{});
}    

function getAlbum(feed_url)
{
    callGetAjax(absolute_path+'/feed/'+feed_url)
    .success(function(data)
    {
    })
    .error(function(xhr, statusText)
    {//console.log(statusText);
    })
    .done(function(data)
    {
        var loaded = 0;
        album_title = data.album.album_title;
        $('h1#gallery-title').html(album_title);

        $.each(data.album.content,function (index,content)
        {
            // Creates a new column for every image element
            var column  = $('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2"></div>'),
                item = $('<a/>')
                    .append($('<img class="img-responsive">').attr('src', content.photo))
                    .attr('href', content.target)
                    .attr('title', content.title)
                    .attr('data-gallery', '')
                    .appendTo(column)
                    .colorbox({rel:'gallery', speed:0, maxWidth:'95%', maxHeight:'95%'});

            // Append column instance to the album container
            album_container.append(column);

        });


    }); 
}
```

---

If you're also looking for a review of your code, may I suggest you transition away from the `jqXHR.success()` and `jqXHR.error()` methods? They have been deprecated in favour of the `jqXHR.done()` and `jqXHR.fail()` methods. Using promises, we have a backbone that looks like this:

```
var album_container = $('div#album');

function callGetAjax(url)
{
    return $.get(url,{});
}    

function getAlbum(feed_url)
{
    // Store returned promise from $.get() in a variable
    var ajaxCall = callGetAjax(absolute_path+'/feed/'+feed_url);

    // Now we listen to the promise
    ajaxCall
    .done(function(data) {

        var loaded = 0;
        album_title = data.album.album_title;
        $('h1#gallery-title').html(album_title);

        $.each(data.album.content,function (index,content)
        {

            var column  = $('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2"></div>'),
                item = $('<a/>')
                    .append($('<img class="img-responsive">').attr('src', content.photo))
                    .attr({
                        'href': content.target,
                        'title': content.title,
                        'data-gallery': ''
                    })
                    .appendTo(column)
                    .colorbox({rel:'gallery', speed:0, maxWidth:'95%', maxHeight:'95%'});

            album_container.append(column);

        });


    })
     .fail(function(xhr, statusText) {
        // Log error
        // console.log(statusText);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Also I realized that you're listening to both `.success()` and `.done()` in your code, which is redundant. Just updated my answer to reflect the use of better AJAX practices, such as listening to the promise and using `.done()` and `.fail()` instead of the old, deprecated `.success()` and `.error()`. Also, for non-boolean attributes, use `.attr()` instead of `.prop()` ;)